# SWT Shell - Internal Padding/Border

Tags: java, swt

I have a SWT Shell that has some type of unknown padding or border that I can't get rid of. Below is a screenshot of what I'm talking about. The border is question is green. How can I get rid of it as my elements would look better pressed directly against the side of the shell?

Thanks in advance :D

[image: screenshot of border]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell rootShell = new Shell(display);
    rootShell.setBackground(SWTGraphicUtil.getColorSafely(0, 255, 0));

    GridLayout rootLayout = new GridLayout();
    rootLayout.numColumns = 3;
    rootLayout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
    rootLayout.verticalSpacing = 0;
    rootLayout.marginTop = rootLayout.marginRight = rootLayout.marginBottom = rootLayout.marginLeft = 0;
    rootShell.setLayout(rootLayout);

    Label lbl = new Label(rootShell, SWT.NONE);
    lbl.setText("WHAT WHAT WHAT WHAT WHAT WHAT WHAT");
    lbl.setBackground(SWTGraphicUtil.getColorSafely(255, 0, 0));

    Label lbl2 = new Label(rootShell, SWT.NONE);
    lbl2.setText("WHAT WHAT WHAT WHAT WHAT WHAT WHAT");
    lbl2.setBackground(SWTGraphicUtil.getColorSafely(255, 0, 255));

    Label lbl3 = new Label(rootShell, SWT.NONE);
    lbl3.setText("WHAT WHAT WHAT WHAT WHAT WHAT WHAT");
    lbl3.setBackground(SWTGraphicUtil.getColorSafely(0, 0, 255));

    rootShell.pack();

    rootShell.open();
    while (!rootShell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set two more variables for your `rootLayout`:

```java
rootLayout.marginWidth = 0;
rootLayout.marginHeight = 0;
```

This should remove the "padding" (which is in fact a margin ;)).

Comment: What a rookie mistake. Thanks for the help! :D